CV-kNN performing worse than kNN
I have been writing some code which compares some basic classifiers. Just wondering if CV-kNN can perform worse than regular kNN when checking performance on test data?
We train the models using a training sample of size 200. For CV I used 10 folds and picked the optimal k value (averaged over 50 samplings of the training data). Could it be the case this k-value fits the training data too well so the error in the test data is worse off?
If this last bit can occur, when is it best to use CV and to avoid it?

In particular, k-fold cross validation provides a statistically more reliable estimate of the model performance than a single training/test set split. So, in your case, the k-fold cross validated model's performance metrics will be more "reliable" than your "regular", as you say, kNN. Hence, the k-fold cross validated metrics could technically be "worse" than without k-fold cross validation; but, the k-fold cross validated metrics are more "reliable".
Your dataset is very small (200 observations), so a single train-test split could be, as some put it, "noisy". So, k-fold CV could be the way to go, if you want.
For your last question, k-fold CV is a lot of times a good thing: it could be good in cases of a small dataset, and is more statistically "reliable" than a single train-test split. For when not to use k-fold CV, see this Cross-Validated question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320154/when-not-to-use-cross-validation
